# Want to change the Cell background color in wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am binding Rows with Classes.

On each binding Row i want change the Cell back ground color on base of cell value.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtstandardview" BorderThickness="0" Height="429"  Width="688" BorderBrush="Aqua" MouseLeftButtonDown="dtstandardview_MouseRightButtonUp_1"
                     GridLinesVisibility="None" MouseRightButtonUp="dtstandardview_MouseRightButtonUp_1" 
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" 
                      CanUserDeleteRows="False"  AlternationCount="2" CanUserResizeRows="False" Sorting="dtstandardview_Sorting_1"
                     Background="#DCDCDC" HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                      RowHeight="27" SelectionUnit="FullRow" CanUserAddRows="False" MinRowHeight="27" LoadingRow="dtstandardview_LoadingRow" LoadingRowDetails="dtstandardview_LoadingRowDetails" Loaded="dtstandardview_Loaded" Initialized="dtstandardview_Initialized" CellEditEnding="dtstandardview_CellEditEnding" AutoGeneratingColumn="dtstandardview_AutoGeneratingColumn" UnloadingRow="dtstandardview_UnloadingRow" UnloadingRowDetails="dtstandardview_UnloadingRowDetails" SelectionChanged="dtstandardview_SelectionChanged"    >
                <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="dataGridRowSelected"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF0000"/>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"  Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#cde0e5" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#cde0e5" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#404040"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="DataContext">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}">
                                    <TextBlock.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Color="#FF000000" Direction="-60" Opacity="0.32" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                    </TextBlock.Effect>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,5" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>

                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#404040"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="DataContext">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}">
                                    <TextBlock.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Color="#FF000000" Direction="-60" Opacity="0.32" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                    </TextBlock.Effect>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"  Value="True">
                                <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#c7dae0" />
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#c7dae0"></Setter>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />-->
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                                <Storyboard x:Key="SelectedOn">
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="select_gradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                                <Storyboard x:Key="SelectedOff">
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="select_gradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                                <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn">
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="hover_gradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.85" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.65" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                                <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff">
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="hover_gradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                            <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>

                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="hover_gradient"  StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}"/>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="highlight" Margin="1" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Grid.Column="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource MouseOverHighlightBrush}" Fill="{DynamicResource MouseOverHighlightBrush}"/>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="select_gradient" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Fill="{DynamicResource PressedBrush}" Stroke="{DynamicResource PressedBorderBrush}"/>

                                                    <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                                    <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                                                    <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>

                                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                            </Border>
                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" SourceName="DGR_Border">
                                                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}" x:Name="HoverOff_BeginStoryboard" />
                                                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}" x:Name="HoverOn_BeginStoryboard" />
                                                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SelectedOff_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectedOff}" />
                                                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectedOn}" />
                                                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>

                        </Style.Triggers>

                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <DataGrid.RowBackground >
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/ClientApplication;component/Images/second_row_bg.png"/>
                </DataGrid.RowBackground>
                <DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/ClientApplication;component/Images/bonus_progress_bg.png"/>
                </DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground>

                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="#404040" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
                                        <TextBlock.Effect>
                                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Color="#FFFFFF" Direction="-90" Opacity="0.40" ShadowDepth="1"  RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Auto" />
                                        </TextBlock.Effect>
                                    </TextBlock>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/ClientApplication;component/Images/table_bg_header.png"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush   ImageSource="/ClientApplication;component/Images/titel_bg.png"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#404040" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 1, 0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="26" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>







                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>



                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="125" Header="Table" Binding="{Binding Path=Table}"> 
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="101"   Header="Stakes" Binding="{Binding Path=Stakes}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="95" Header="Game" Binding="{Binding Path=Game}" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" Width="86">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:Name="typedatatempl">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="stackpaneltype">
                                    <TextBlock Name="typedate"  Text="{Binding Path=Type}" Margin="2,0,0,2" />

                                    <TextBlock Name="txtblocknumber" Text="{Binding Path=number}" Margin="2, 0, 0, 2" Background="Gray" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10" Foreground="White" Height="13" Width="13" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    <TextBlock Name="txtblockalpha"  Text="{Binding Path=alphabate}" Margin="5,0,0,2" Background="Transparent" FontFamily="Arial" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10" Foreground="White" Height="13" Width="13" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="83" Header="Players" Binding="{Binding Path=Players}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="117" Header="Average Pot" Binding="{Binding Path=Average}"   />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="63" Header="H/Hr" Binding="{Binding Path=hhr}"  />
                </DataGrid.Columns>



            </DataGrid>
```

How  can i change the back color of cell base on value.

I did on dtstandardview_LoadingRow  event but not working .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `Triggers` collection on the `DataGridCell` `Style` add the following

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

And this would be your view model and entity class

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        Items =
            new ObservableCollection<MyEntity>
            {
                new MyEntity(true),
                new MyEntity(false),
                new MyEntity(true)
            };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyEntity> Items { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntity(bool value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: pmacnaughton:  Thanks For the Reply . But i will change the for Row.

Comment: Are you saying that you still can't get it to work or that you've decided to go with changing the whole row instead?

Comment: pmacnaughton:  Thanks For It . Now  i got the idea what i have to do . Again Thanks :)